# Couldn't load XPCOM. Tor browser

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, firefox

When I try to open the Tor browser, I get a Firefox message box, saying: Couldn't load XPCOM . And no, I don't have any Webroot product. Could someone please help me?
I had already asked this question, but no one helped me. Could someone who knows about this problem please help me?